# Apple Mach-O Linker Error Code 1

Tags: ios, xcode

Linker command failed with exit code 1 is in red. How do I fix this? My other question is... I already submitted this app to Xcode and it was working fine the other day. If I cannot correct this.. would I be able to download the one I sent to Apple?

Thank you

```
Ld /Users/StephenRao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RC_Car-crbpfbxfvatakdekmfisaozvrpcg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Helli.app/Helli normal i386
    cd "/Users/StephenRao/Desktop/Helli 2"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/StephenRao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RC_Car-crbpfbxfvatakdekmfisaozvrpcg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/StephenRao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RC_Car-crbpfbxfvatakdekmfisaozvrpcg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/StephenRao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RC_Car-crbpfbxfvatakdekmfisaozvrpcg/Build/Intermediates/RC\ Car.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Helli.build/Objects-normal/i386/Helli.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework iAd -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/StephenRao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RC_Car-crbpfbxfvatakdekmfisaozvrpcg/Build/Intermediates/RC\ Car.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Helli.build/Objects-normal/i386/Helli_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/StephenRao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RC_Car-crbpfbxfvatakdekmfisaozvrpcg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Helli.app/Helli

ld: framework not found AVKit for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*i386* Mac compiler expects AVKit framework suitable for it. But you might have included only device framework. Either including *simulator (i386) framework  or Building application for Device* would help you.